# Some unicode glyphs display as emojis on android

Tags: android, qt, unicode, qml, qt-quick

I have this sequence: `"\u2197\ufe0e"`, which should be a diagonal top-right facing arrow with variation selector "text style". I'm writing my app in qt quick for desktop and android. Here is how it looks on desktop (note the varying colours):

[image: sexy desktop arrows]

And here is what I get on an android emulator:

[image: square android arrows]

As emojis they can't have different colours and are misaligned. How can I make them look like text?

I'm using android api 26 and Qt 5.12.2.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `renderType` of your `Text`? `Text.QtRendering` or `Text.NativeRendering`

Comment: @GrecKo Thanks for suggestion. I tried and neigther render type has fixed the problem sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Different emoji in different platform may have the different appearance, if you want them has same appearance, you should use image and ImageSpan to replace the emoji.

```
TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder("\u2197\ufe0e Your text content");
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.xxx), 0, 2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.setText(builder);
```

Comment: This question is about the Qt framework on Android, the UI is not native.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to write your reply. What you're suggesting is using some android-local code, and right now I don't have any at all! I'm using only Qt provided libraries and evironment and I want it left like that, so using any Java is not an option.